# The incorrect header check error when trying to unzip file with Node.js zlib

Tags: node.js, zlib

I try to unzip a zip file with Node.js app, but using only built-in module(s) e.g. zlib.

I tried this code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const zlib = require('zlib');
const path = require('path');

const zipFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'test.zip');
const unzipDirectory = path.join(__dirname, 'unzipdir');

const readStream = fs.createReadStream(zipFilePath);
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(unzipDirectory);

readStream.pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(writeStream);

writeStream.on('finish', () => {
  console.log('Unzip process completed.');
});

readStream.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('Error reading ZIP file:', err);
});

writeStream.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('Error writing unzip directory:', err);
});
```

but it throws the incorrect header check error. The zip file is zipped with DEFLATE in 7Zip and contains only .txt file.

How to resolve the problem?

Node.js v18

Comment: Are you confusing the GZip format with the (PK)ZIP format?

Comment: @Botje do you mean `createGunzip`? What's the correct method?